# Ethernet speeds drop drastically

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

This might not be the correct community, but it's the closest fit.

When I'm downloading, I have peak speeds of 240+mbps, however my speeds often drop to 480kbps or even lower. I don't see anything else downloading anything (and even if there is, shouldn't my overall speeds remain constant, just the data coming in would be split between the two rather than lowering the data coming in?) Is there a way to fix this? It's really getting in the way of downloading things and playing multiplayer.

As far as my network, I have a Linksys router EA7300 with the most up to date firmware, my house has built in ethernet ports which I'm connected to, Wifi is turned off, and my computer is the #1 prioritized device on the network.

Comment: If you connect a computer directly to your ISP connection, without your router and via a known good patch cord, can you duplicate the issue from multiple different sources?

Comment: @acejavelin does your ISP let you do that? They bond the Mac here to the router. I.e you have to call them to release it.

Comment: Most ISP's that we deal with do not lock the MAC address to a single device, whether cable, DSL, or "direct connection" types, although it is not uncommon to have to power cycle the modem when the device changes to clear the ARP table in the device, especially with customers who use static public IP addresses. Regardless for testing purposes you could temporarily change the MAC address on your adapter to the router's MAC address to test with.

Comment: I connected my PC directly to the modem and it had similar results using a completely different ethernet cable.I still had similar peaks and dropping to 0 occasionally. I was using Steam downloads as a control, I will try downloading on other platforms and seeing if a similar issue occurs.

Comment: What type of connection is this? Can you post the provider name, connection type, (fiber, cable, adsl,etc) & make and model of the modem in question. This sounds like it's a inside wiring, or ISP connection issue to me. The best thing to do if it's a cable connection is checking the logs. It can usually be reached in a browser @ 192.168.100.1

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Ethernet transport from your router to the PC. Either your router is lagging or the ISP is.